# c.active is not a function in chart.js

Tags: javascript, chart.js

Tooltips don't seem to be working on my chart, when I disable chart animations they start working. The error it throws is `Uncaught TypeError: c.active is not a function`. Is there anyway to bypass this or is there an issue with my code (shown below)?

I'm using chart.umd.js v4.3.2 if that helps.

```js
const ctx = gid('myChart')
const _ = new Chart(ctx, {
    type: 'line',
    data: {
        labels: Object.keys(data.timeMap),
        datasets: [{
            data: Object.values(data.timeMap),
            lineTension: 0,
            backgroundColor: 'transparent',
            borderColor: '#007bff',
            borderWidth: 4,
            pointBackgroundColor: '#007bff'
        }]
    },
    options: {
        plugins: {
            legend: {
                display: false
            },
            tooltip: {
                boxPadding: 3
            }
        },
        interaction: {
            mode: 'x',
            intersect: false
        }
    }
})
```